# Query for new column and exponential

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have question in SQL Server, for the below requirement.
I tried multiple codes combination I'm getting error.

Existing code:

```
SELECT *
  FROM [ION_Data].[dbo].[DataLog2]
  where (TimestampUTC BETWEEN '2020-03-10 07:00:00.0000000' AND '2020-03-10 07:03:00.0000000') and (QuantityID = 129) and SourceID IN (40,9,10)
```

Gives below output.

```
ID          Value       SourceID QuantityID TimestampUTC
1275494368  27816141    9        129        10/03/2020 07:00:00
1275495389  27816157    9        129        10/03/2020 07:01:00
1275495579  27816185    9        129        10/03/2020 07:02:00
1275494243  30821687    10       129        10/03/2020 07:00:00
1275495281  30821703    10       129        10/03/2020 07:01:00
1275495467  30821734    10       129        10/03/2020 07:02:00
1275494428  1.60E-16    40       129        10/03/2020 07:00:00
1275495162  1.60E-16    40       129        10/03/2020 07:01:00
1275495932  1.60E-16    40       129        10/03/2020 07:02:00
```

Tried:

Cast, Conversion methods etc

Requirement:

1. Remove Exponential in all ‘Value’ column when displaying, convert to may be ‘0’ for exponent
2. Display a new column ‘ValueDIFF’ with difference between row value (Bottom row minus Toprow) based on SourceID - for given period in query (last row blank)

```
ID          Value    SourceID QuantityID TimestampUTC         Value Diff
1275494368  27816141 9        129        10/03/2020 07:00:00  16
1275495389  27816157 9        129        10/03/2020 07:01:00  28
1275495579  27816185 9        129        10/03/2020 07:02:00    
1275494243  30821687 10       129        10/03/2020 07:00:00  16
1275495281  30821703 10       129        10/03/2020 07:01:00  31
1275495467  30821734 10       129        10/03/2020 07:02:00    
1275494428  0        40       129        10/03/2020 07:00:00  0
1275495162  0        40       129        10/03/2020 07:01:00  0
1275495932  0        40       129        10/03/2020 07:02:00
```

Comment: What is the data type of column `Value`?

Comment: LAG() or LEAD() functions is what you are looking for to get the value diff.

Comment: Data type of 'Value' is float

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
select id, cast(value as decimal(20, 0)) as value, sourceid, quantityid, timestamputc,
       cast(lead(value) over (partition by sourceid order by timestampUTC) - value as decimal(20, 0)) as diff
from t
where QuantityID = 129 and
      timestampUTC >= '2020-03-10T07:00:00' and
      timestampUTC >= '2020-03-10T07:03:00'
```

Comment: I ran the code now, TimestampUTC sorting became random so new difference column gives random values, if u see my initial code, it will be sorted by SourceID then by TimestampUTC and then difference is applied. also when I add SourceID IN (40,9,10) next to Quantity ID it give error. could you pls check

Comment: Thanks! @Gordon Linoff. I did a small edit in your code it works. However  exponential values are gone from old value column, the new Column 'Value Diff' still has exponential values. I tyring how to solve it. https://ibb.co/0mZgmJW

Comment: @user13153021 . . . Just cast that to a decimal as well.

Comment: I got the below message. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 Incorrect syntax near '20'.

Comment: @user13153021 . . . The `cast()` should work the same as in the first line of the query.

Comment: Thanks! @Gordon Linoff ...yes I tried cast still the same, exponential is coming in diff...  select ID, cast(Value as decimal(20, 0)) as Value, SourceID,TimestampUTC, 
       (lead(Value) over (partition by SourceID order by TimestampUTC) - cast(Value as decimal(20, 0))) as diff
from t
where QuantityID = 129 and SourceID IN (40) and
      TimestampUTC >= '2020-03-10 07:00:00.0000000' and
      TimestampUTC <= '2020-03-10 07:05:00.0000000'

Comment: @user13153021 . . . That is not the code in this answer.